# Compiling phonegap application problem

Tags: android, cordova

I've followed the installation instruction to the letter.
I've installed the latest JDK ADK ApacheAnt and Ruby installations.
I've setup the JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, ANT_HOME paths, and added JAVA_HOME\bin; ANDROID_HOME\tools; ANT_HOME\bin; phonegap\bin to the path.
However, when i try to run:

```
C:\phonegap\bin>ruby ./droidgap c:\android-sdk-windows test com.my.test c:\www c
:\temp\test3
```

I get:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load --
C:/phonegap/bin/lib/generate.rb (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from ./droidgap:4:in `<main>'
```

So ruby is looking for the lib dir in /bin? Something is wrong here.
So if i copy the lib dir in /bin and run the same command again, i get nothing.
No output, and the destination dir does not exist.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the head of phonegap android master on github then you will want to refer to the readme file in the repo. The way you are running droidgap above only works on versions <= 0.9.1.

Comment: How does the new version work?
More specifically, how do i export a version to eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ruby 1.9.1 installed. It does NOT work with ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: 
http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/a875b873405ec82c/45c355c42163ead8?lnk=gst&q=electronbender#45c355c42163ead8

Thanks for everyone's help!